# Serialize a custom class as a primitive type with protobuf-net

Tags: c#, .net, protobuf-net

I am using a custom struct "PreciseTimeSpan" that consists like the regular .NET TimeSpan of a ticks value of datatype long. I want to serialize PreciseTimeSpan fields by serializing the ticks value as varint. Until now I created a private property for each PreciseTimeSpan field that performed the conversion from and to long. But this is quite inconvenient. Is it possible to serialize a custom class / struct as a primitive type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whilst protobuf-net does support surrogate serialization types, it does *not* currently allow these to be mixed with primitive types. It is theoretically possible that it could do so, but: not today. If you really want, I could investigate this option.

Comment: I want to avoid the overhead of a nested message, therefore I don't want to use a surrogate. I think I will create a VS snippet for my conversion property.